# Merge two XML files in C# where the tags ID is the same

Tags: c#, xml

I need to merge two XML files in C# where AccountNumber is the same in these XMLfiles. 
I have about 400 accounts in the XML file.

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Account>
  <Table1>
    <Id>12</Id>
    <AccountNumber>5050</AccountNumber>
    <External>false</External>
  </Table1>
</Account>
```

XML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Account>
  <Table1>
    <AccountNumber>5050</AccountNumber>
     <ProductDate>2017-12-18</ProductDate>
    <ProductNr>294</ProductNr>
  </Table1>
</Account>
```

Så the result will be like this

XML 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Account>
  <Table1>
    <Id>12</Id>
    <AccountNumber>5050</AccountNumber>
    <External>false</External>
    <ProductDate>2017-12-18</ProductDate>
    <ProductNr>294</ProductNr>
  </Table1>
</Account>
```

Comment: I think you should be able to adapt this answer to solve your problem: [Merge two xml file nodes with same node value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577872/6610379)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public class XmlMatcher
{
    public XDocument MatchXmlFiles(XDocument doc1, XDocument doc2)
    {
        XDocument result = new XDocument(); 
        List<XElement> doc1Elements = doc1.Root.Elements().ToList();
        List<XElement> doc2Elements = doc2.Root.Elements().ToList();


        XElement accountElement = new XElement("Account");
        result = new XDocument(accountElement);

        for (int i = 0; i < doc1Elements.Count(); i++)
        {
            XmlDocument subDoc = new XmlDocument();
            subDoc.LoadXml(doc1Elements[i].ToString());

            string tableName     = subDoc.FirstChild.Name;
            string accountNumber = doc1Elements[i].Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "AccountNumber").FirstOrDefault().Value;

            List<XElement> doc1Childs = doc1Elements[i].Elements().ToList();
            List<XElement> doc2Childs = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(accountNumber) > -1).FirstOrDefault().Elements().ToList();                 

            XElement tblElement   = new XElement(tableName); 
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("Id"           , GetChildValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "Id")));  
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("AccountNumber", accountNumber));
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("External"     , GetChildValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "External")));
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("ProductDate"  , GetChildValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "ProductDate")));
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("ProductNr"    , GetChildValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "ProductNr")));
            accountElement.Add(tblElement);

        }  
        return result;
    }

    public object GetChildValue(List<XElement> doc1Childs, List<XElement> doc2Childs, string name)
    {
        object value = string.Empty;

        XElement child = doc1Childs.Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();

        if (child != null)
        {
            value = child.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            child = doc2Childs.Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();

            if(child != null)
                value = child.Value;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
XmlMatcher xmlManager = new XmlMatcher();

XDocument xml1 = XDocument.Load("Your Xm1 Path");
XDocument xml2 = XDocument.Load("Your Xm2 Path"); 
XDocument xml3 = xmlManager.MatchXmlFiles(xml1, xml2);
xml3.Save("Your Xm3 Path");
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I'm getting NullReferenceException was unhandled on this line 
 List<XElement> doc2Childs = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(accountNumber) > -1).FirstOrDefault().Elements().ToList();

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GetClients.exe

Comment: AccountNumber field must be present in all records in both files you use. Can you check this?

Comment: Can you tell me the result when you check?

Comment: Yes Accountnumber exist in both. It works fine when I online have for few clients in both. By example if I have 5 clients in each file, then it worked fine. But I have about 400, and these 400 clients exists in both xml files

Comment: Okay.  What is the value of the variable "i" when the code gives an error?

Comment: I run it again and i = 42

Comment: Can you write the 43rd account record in the 2nd file(xml2.xml)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213748/discussion-between-djxenon-and-hidayet-r-colkusu).